# Inserting a multi-dimensional php array into a mysqli database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

the code here,does not work

```
$sub1="Mathematics";
$sub2="Chemistry";
$sub3="Biology";
$sub4="Hindi";
$sub5="History";
$sub6="Malayalam";
$sub7="Physics";

$timetable = array
  (
  array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","ThursdaY","Friday"),
  array($sub1,$sub1,$sub1,$sub1,$sub1),
  array($sub3,$sub2,$sub6,"Arts",$sub5),
  array($sub2,"Ethics","science",$sub3,"science"),
  array($sub4,$sub3,$sub5,$sub7,$sub3),
  array("Arts",$sub6,$sub5,$sub2,$sub7),
  array($sub6,$sub2,$sub4,$sub6,$sub5),
  array($sub5,$sub4,$sub3,$sub4,$sub6)
);
 for($i=$q;$i<=7+$q;$i++)
    {
     $query = "INSERT INTO `class`(`class`, `monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`, `saturday`) VALUES ('$class','$array[$i][0]', '$array[$i][1]', '$array[$i][2]', '$array[$i][3]', '$array[$i][4]', '1')";

           $que=mysqli_query($obj->conn,$query);  
}
```

I would like to insert it into a mysqli table where the week of the subject array (sub1, sub2, sub3,sub4,sub5) are the column titles and each subsequent array is a row in the table.

Could anyone advice as to the best way to do this as I have hit a wall and it has left me with a hurting head!

Comment: `$array` is not defined.

Comment: but not that problem . thank you sir

Comment: Are you sure it is '$class' and not $class the value you are trying to insert ??

Comment: sorry i miss that code $class has value but that code not work

Comment: Another point is if your loop is to work for 7 repetition  why you are making it so complex and for every operation there will one extra operation before checking ;$i<=7+$q condition ?

Comment: @arunsasi  just do not add quote and try  and do not forget to tag when you are replying .like I have done here.

Comment: $q=5 class no  that value

Comment: @arunsasi what is $array ? are you sure about $timetable array ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;    
for($timetable as $tt) {

    if( $i != 1 ) {

        $query = "INSERT into class (`class`, `monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`, `saturday`) VALUES (`$class`, `$tt[0]`, `$tt[1]`, `$tt[2]`, `$tt[3]`, `$tt[4]`, 1)";

        $que = mysqli_query($obj->conn, $query);
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Try this! Hope will work for you.

Comment: At least add quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you can understand what I am trying to say on your code .

```
$sub1="Mathematics";
$sub2="Chemistry";
$sub3="Biology";
$sub4="Hindi";
$sub5="History";
$sub6="Malayalam";
$sub7="Physics";

$class = 'XII';

$timetable = array
  (
  array($sub1,$sub1,$sub1,$sub1,$sub1),
  array($sub3,$sub2,$sub6,"Arts",$sub5),
  array($sub2,"Ethics","science",$sub3,"science"),
  array($sub4,$sub3,$sub5,$sub7,$sub3),
  array("Arts",$sub6,$sub5,$sub2,$sub7),
  array($sub6,$sub2,$sub4,$sub6,$sub5),
  array($sub5,$sub4,$sub3,$sub4,$sub6)
);

 for($i=0;$i<=7;$i++) {
     $query = "INSERT INTO `class`(`class`, `monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`, `saturday`) VALUES ($class,$timetable[$i][0], $timetable[$i][1], $timetable[$i][2], $timetable[$i][3], $timetable[$i][4],1)";

           $que=mysqli_query($obj->conn,$query);  
}
```

I have some assumption here, like `$class = 'XII'` and `"class"`  table has 7 fields `'class', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'` where `'saturday'` seems to be holiday or something as it is getting 1 always.

or instead for you cna consider using foreach

```
 foreach($timetable as $ttable){
         $query = "INSERT INTO `class`(`class`, `monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`, `saturday`) VALUES ($class,$ttable[0], $ttable[1], $ttable[2], $ttable[3], $ttable[4],1)";

         $que=mysqli_query($obj->conn,$query);  
  }
```

why you have a 5th element in 3rd child array of $timetable if you are inserting 1 for it everytime, I do not understand that too .